# 16.04 - DNS problem when waking laptop up from suspend-mode

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Dell XPS 15 9550.

Since one week ago (which probably matches last kernel update), every time I wake up my Laptop from suspend-mode, it correctly connects to the WiFi, but then it can't resolve any hostname (Google Chrome raises "DNS FINISHED BAD_CONFIG" and even ssh can't resolve server names).

This happen only when waking laptop up from suspend-mode. If I run

`sudo service network-manager restart`

then everything comes back to normal. I really have no idea of what's happening. Config or sys changes may be occurred only through automatic updates (kernel updates included).

P.S. I've already tried to reset resolvconf when the problem occurs, but no luck.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

just found this in syslog

```
brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
```

The strange thing is that I have an `brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin` in `/lib/firmware` , but it has extension `.bin` as all others drivers, so I don't know why the kernel is searching for an `.txt` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here on XPS13 9350 running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10.

I've found a solution/workaround, but I have to admit that I don't fully understand *why* it works.

I noticed that I kept seeing references to 127.0.1.1 as a nameserver, particularly in /etc/resolv.conf. Once I found that, it led me to the solution here:

[nameserver 127.0.1.1 in resolv.conf won't go away!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserv/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.confer-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away)

The issue is with NetworkManager.  It seems that it had the bogus notion that I was running a DNS server on my local machine, despite the fact that I don't. (This seems really silly as a default behavior, though, so I'm willing to concede I may have accidentally poked something or installed something that made it think so)

Regardless, it can be fixed by simply commenting out the following line in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

I've tried several reboots and sleep/wake cycles since making the change, all with positive results.  I'll try to update this if I run into any future issues. Good Luck!

Comment: disabling NM's dnsmasq seems to be working fine! The only thing I dont understand is why this problem occurs only since last week (I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 15 since April 2016). Is this the result of an apt upgrade, perhaps? Anyway, thank you!

Comment: This was a fresh install for me, so I'm not really sure why it would just stop working correctly. /n can you check your apt logs to see what packages were upgraded around that time?  It would probably have something to do with DNS.