# Cannot ping by host name

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, tcpdump

I have a strange situation. Pinging by ip works fine, but by host name fails.
My observations:

```
nslookup -type=ns google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

In one window I called:

```
ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

and in the other window I had this:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i eno1 |grep -A5 172.27.1.100.53 # this is my dns server
11:06:57.336938 IP 172.27.6.77.48852 > 172.27.1.100.53: 61526+ A? google.com. (28)
11:06:57.337151 IP 172.27.1.100.53 > 172.27.6.77.48852: 61526 1/0/0 A 172.217.12.110 (44)
11:06:57.337170 IP 172.27.6.77 > 172.27.1.100: ICMP 172.27.6.77 udp port 48852 unreachable, length 80
```

As you can see in the tcpdump there was a response from DNS server and google.com was properly resolved: 172.217.12.110.

What's going on here? Can I somehow debug it more?

I know that when I restart my network it would work fine, because it happened few times earlier. This is only workaround and it doesn't resolve my isssue.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 (desktop).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change your nameserver to 8.8.8.8 in /etc/resolv.conf ?

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestions. I have disabled dnsmasq (so it caused change of /etc/resolv.conf) and now it looks it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into these issues:
[nameserver 127.0.1.1 in resolv.conf won't go away!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away)
[How do I fix DNS resolving which doesn't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368435/how-do-i-fix-dns-resolving-which-doesnt-work-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-s)
and made a trick with disabling line "dns=dnsmasq" in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf .

It looks this solves my issue.